# Perl: Monitor a background process's output without waiting for it to complete

Tags: perl, process, background, monitor

I'm attempting to write a manager in Perl to automate a bioinformatics pipeline my lab has been using. (The REPET pipeline, for anyone who's interested.) The pipeline has eight steps, several of which are broken down into substeps which can be run in parallel.  Most notably, step 3 is broken down into three parts, and step 4 into three corresponding parts.  Each part of step 3 can be run independently, and its corresponding part in step 4 can be started as soon as its step 3 companion is finished.  I'd like my manager to be able to launch step 3 in three parallel threads, and, for each thread, move on to step 4 as soon as step 3 is finished.  The best way I can think to do that is to monitor the output of each process. The output from each step looks like this:

```
START TEdenovo.py (2012-08-23 11:20:10)
version 2.0
project name = dm3_chr2L
project directory = /home/<etc>
beginning of step 1
submitting job(s) with groupid 'dm3_chr2L_TEdenovo_prepareBatches' (2012-08-23 11:20:10)
waiting for 1 job(s) with groupid 'dm3_chr2L_TEdenovo_prepareBatches' (2012-08-23 11:20:10)
execution time per job: n=1 mean=2.995 var=0.000 sd=0.000 min=2.995 med=2.995 max=2.995
step 1 finished successfully
version 2.0
END TEdenovo.py (2012-08-23 11:20:25)
```

That's the output for step 1, but in step 3, when "step 3 finished successfully" appears in the output, it's safe to move on to step 4. The problem has been successfully tabulating the output for three of these processes as they run at once. Essentially, this is the behavior that I want (pseudocode):

```
my $log31 = `TEdenovo.py [options] &`;
my $log32 = `TEdenovo.py [options] &`;
my $log33 = `TEdenovo.py [options] &`;

while(1) {
    #start step 41 if $log31 =~ /step 3 finished successfully/;
    #start step 42 if $log32 =~ /step 3 finished successfully/;
    #start step 43 if $log33 =~ /step 3 finished successfully/;
    #monitor logs 41, 42, 43 similarly
    last if #all logs read "finished successfully"
    sleep(5);
}

#move on to step 5
```

The problem is that evoking a process with backticks causes perl to wait until that process has finished to move on; as I discovered, it isn't like with system(), where you can spin something into a background process with & and then proceed immediately. As far as I know, there isn't a good way to use system() to get the effect I'm looking for. I suppose I could do this:

```
system("TEdenovo.py [options] & > log31.txt");
```

And then poll log31.txt periodically to see whether "finished successfully" has appeared, but that seems unecessarily messy.

I've also tried opening the process in a filehandle:

```
open(my $step3, "TEdenovo.py [options] |");
my @log3;

while(1)
{
    push(@log3, <$step3>);
    last if grep("step 3 finished successfully", @log3);
    sleep(5);
}
```

...but, once again, Perl waits until the process has finished in order to move on (in this case, at the push()). I tried the above with $| both set and unset.

So, the essence of my question is: Is there a way to capture the standard output of a running background process in perl?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

maybe you could try

```
open(my $step3, "TEdenovo.py [options] |");

while(<$step3>)
{
    last if /step 3 finished successfully/;
}
```

instead of while(1) ?

Comment: `push @log3,<$step3>` evaluates `<$step3>` in list context, which waits for eof (i.e., for the process to finish).

Comment: Aha, mob, your suggestion appears to have done it. Instead of reading into an array, I tried concatenating one line at a time, as `$log3 .= <$step3>`, and it's moving on into the wait loop as I was hoping. Now there's only one mini-issue remaining: doing it this way only picks up one line of the output at a time, whereas I'd like to slurp it all up at each go. Using file slurp mode `$/ = undef` also searches for EOF, doesn't it? So how might I get the entirety of the output at each step? I won't be surprised if there isn't a way; after all, that's sort of what EOF is for, isn't it?

Comment: I'm using `while(1)` still instead of Nahuel's suggestion because I'm not going to have all of the loop condition information available going into the loop. I'll need to monitor eight processes for EOF, and  only two of them will be started as I head into the loop. i.e., I won't have those filehandles open yet, and eof() returns 1 for an unopened filehandle, which will wrongly evaluate as an exit condition for the loop. So then I'd have to also monitor the contents of each log as a loop condition... it just gets messy; easier to monitor the loop conditions from within the loo pin this case.

Answer (score 0):

The approach of using `open` and reading from the pipehandle is <strike>the</strike> a correct approach. If Nahuel's suggestion of reading from the handle in scalar context doesn't help, you could still be suffering from buffering.

`$|` changes the buffering behavior of Perl's output, but not the behavior of any external programs called from Perl. You have to use an external program that doesn't buffer its output. In this case, I believe this is possible by passing the `-u` option to python:

```
open(my $step3, "|-", "python -u TEdenovo.py [more options]");
```